# How do you replace an object's mesh and armature with the same object that has the updated mesh and armature?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I have a model of a firearm without the magazine and connected it to my arms armature (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> in *Pose Mode* and choosing *Bone*) for animations and it works fine.

However, when it came to animate the reload animation, I added a magazine and its bone in the firearm's .blend file (while keeping the same old armature with the same properties, names, etc... and just added another child bone and mesh of the root bone) and then copy pasted it into my arms' .blend file.

I made sure to delete the old one so that the bone names won't change and connected the new one to my right palm bone (using the same method). However, it somehow deformed the weapon mesh, so I enabled the "Keep Transform" option and it seems fine at first but when I moved the palm bone, the whole arms and weapon deformed, however if I move any other bones except the palm bone, it moves normally.

Is there a way to just select the old weapon mesh and armature and click "Replace" or some sort to replace it with the new one while keeping the same position, rotation, scale and properties (including being connected to the right palm bone)?